# error in react-native-google-signin in react native

Tags: react-native

Code:

```
import {
  GoogleSigninButton,GoogleSignin
} from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
const CLIENT_ID = "client_id";

<GoogleSigninButton
              clientId={CLIENT_ID}
              render={(renderProps) => (
                <Button
                  className={classes.googleButton}
                  color="secondary"
                  fullWidth
                  onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                  disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Google Sign In
                </Button>
              )}
              onSuccess={googleSuccess}
              onFailure={googleError}
              cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
            />
```

Error message:
ERROR  RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly linked. Please read the readme, setup and troubleshooting instructions carefully or try manual linking. If you're using Expo, please use expo-google-sign-in. This is because Expo does not support custom native modules.
ERROR  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNGoogleSignin.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED')
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

Comment: Are you using expo

Comment: Yes I am using expo

Comment: The error you posted says: If you're using Expo, please use expo-google-sign-in.

Comment: for me the package name in app.json -> android.package and the value in google cloud android client were not matching. Also, the SHA fingerprint was different. Once i fixed those 2 values, this error went away